# socket programming: what is wrong here?

Tags: sockets, tcp

Code

```
struct sockaddr_in ser;
...
#line 68
fprintf(stderr, "Can't find host %s\n", inet_ntoa(ser.sin_addr));
```

Compile (gcc ...) warning

```
68: warning: format '%s' expects type 'char *', but argument 3 has type 'int'
```

but "inet_ntoa()" does should return "char *", right?

Comment: ok, missing #include <arpa/inet.h>, but what is the default that's been taken and where is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, functions which are used without an active prototype return an `int`. This behaviour is specified in the ISO C standard (at least in C90).

You need to include the header file where that function is declared so that the compiler has the right prototype for it.